# Keep the first row on 2 sheets identical, regardless of changes on either sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want the first row of 2 sheets to be the same.
For example, if both sheets first row starts out as 'USA', 'Canada' in A1, B1, and then on Sheet1 I enter 'Brazil' into C1, and then 'Germany' into D1 on Sheet2, BOTH sheets will read 'USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'Germany', without having to manually merge both sheets every time I make a change.
Is this possible in Excel?  If so, how?

Comment: Transferring to both directions requires a macro. If you're happy with one direction too (e.g. Sheet2's first row is read-only and changes in sheet1 are reflected there), then it's easy to do with standard formula. If you decide to use macro, there're several great tutorials on the internet.

Comment: would you be open to explaining the method you described, and possibly linking one of those tutorials?  I am not even sure how to go about searching for this type of functionality.